# android scrollview inside scrollview scrolling problem

Tags: android, scrollview

I have added an `AbsoluteLayout` on `ScrollView`. Up to this, it worked fine. 
After that, I added `ScrollView` on above mentioned `AbsoluteLayout`. Now I have

```
 ScrollView -> AbsoluteLayout -> ScrollView -> AbsoluteLayout
```

This structure also works fine. But when I try to scroll inner `ScrollView`, 
it scrolls slightly and after that outer scrollview starts scrolling.

How can I restrict scrolling outer `ScrollView` when I am scrolling inner `ScrollView`?

Comment: In number of occasions Android devs have said that you should not put two a scroll view inside another. It won't work. You probably have to fins another solution for your app. :(

Comment: Both scrollviews are scrolling horizontally or vertically? Or one of them's scrolling vertically and the other one's scrolling horizontally? If this's the case, you can use onInterceptTouchEvent...

Comment: otherwise, you may prefer to use expandableList instead of inner scrollView because of Juhani's comment...